# Lambda and Anonymous Function Invoke Function Invoked Twice

Tags: kotlin, lambda, jvm, anonymous-function, invoke

Inspecting the stack trace of an anonymously created an invoked lambda shows that for the same class and the same method, the invoke function of the lambda were invoked twice.

**Is there an explanation for that?**

`_03_LambdaAndAnonymousFunctionInvokeFunctionInvokedTwice_Test` Entire Kotlin File (lines 1 to 23)

```
package _z_additional

import org.junit.jupiter.api.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.min

/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749419/lambda-and-anonymous-function-invoke-function-invoked-twice?noredirect=1#comment111005433_62749419*/
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
object _03_LambdaAndAnonymousFunctionInvokeFunctionInvokedTwice_Test { /*line 9*/

    @Test
    fun demonstrate_twiceInvoked() {
        ({
            val stack = Throwable().stackTrace /*line 14*/
            val stackInfo = StringJoiner("    <==    ")
            for (i in stack.indices) {
                stackInfo.add("${stack[i].className} || ${stack[i].methodName} || ${stack[i].lineNumber}")
            }
            println(stackInfo)
        })()
    }

}
```

*Output*

> _z_additional._03_LambdaAndAnonymousFunctionInvokeFunctionInvokedTwice_Test$demonstrate_twiceInvoked$1 || invoke || 14    <==    _z_additional._03_LambdaAndAnonymousFunctionInvokeFunctionInvokedTwice_Test$demonstrate_twiceInvoked$1 || invoke || 9    <==    _z_additional._03_LambdaAndAnonymousFunctionInvokeFunctionInvokedTwice_Test || demonstrate_twiceInvoked || 13    <==    jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl || invoke0 || -2    <==    jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl || invoke || 62    <==    jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl || invoke || 43    <==    java.lang.reflect.Method || invoke || 566    <==    org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils || invokeMethod || 686    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation || proceed || 60    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation || proceed || 131    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension || intercept || 149    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension || interceptTestableMethod || 140    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension || interceptTestMethod || 84    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall || lambda$ofVoidMethod$0 || 115    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker || lambda$invoke$0 || 105    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation || proceed || 106    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain || proceed || 64    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain || chainAndInvoke || 45    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain || invoke || 37    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker || invoke || 104    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker || invoke || 98    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor || lambda$invokeTestMethod$6 || 212    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector || execute || 73    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor || invokeTestMethod || 208    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor || execute || 137    <==    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor || execute || 71    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$5 || 135    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector || execute || 73    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$7 || 125    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node || around || 135    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$8 || 123    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector || execute || 73    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || executeRecursively || 122    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || execute || 80    <==    java.util.ArrayList || forEach || 1540    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService || invokeAll || 38    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$5 || 139    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector || execute || 73    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$7 || 125    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node || around || 135    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$8 || 123    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector || execute || 73    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || executeRecursively || 122    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || execute || 80    <==    java.util.ArrayList || forEach || 1540    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService || invokeAll || 38    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$5 || 139    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector || execute || 73    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$7 || 125    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node || around || 135    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || lambda$executeRecursively$8 || 123    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector || execute || 73    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || executeRecursively || 122    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask || execute || 80    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService || submit || 32    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor || execute || 57    <==    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine || execute || 51    <==    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher || execute || 248    <==    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher || lambda$execute$5 || 211    <==    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher || withInterceptedStreams || 226    <==    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher || execute || 199    <==    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher || execute || 132    <==    com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner || startRunnerWithArgs || 69    <==    com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater || startRunnerWithArgs || 33    <==    com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter || prepareStreamsAndStart || 230    <==    com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter || main || 58

Comment: It would help if you gave us the whole stack.

Comment: @rtsketo updated question

Comment: It would help even more if it weren't impossible to read squeezed into one enormous line...

Comment: It's a combination of intellij and junit runners.

Comment: I think seeing the full trace is irrelevant. But, it's there. It probably has to do with how Kotlin handles lambda and anonymous functions. This doesn't happen for function objects, invocable objects nor function declarations.

Comment: If the function was evaluated twice, you saw two different stack traces. All you are seeing, is an additional stack frame. Surely, it would help to see line 13, but it seems like this some adapter method, Kotlin’s equivalent to bridge methods or such alike.